# Show that $c^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$

Tags: number-theory

Let $p \equiv 1 \pmod4$ be a prime. Write $p$ in the form $p=a^2+b^2$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers. Let $c \equiv ab^{-1} \pmod p$. Show that $c^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$

$p = 4n+1$ where $n$ is an integer.
$c = ab^{-1} +pm$ where $m$ is an integer.
Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: We have $a^2\equiv -b^2\pmod{p}$. Multiply both sides  by the square of $b^{-1}$.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Is $c$ the speed of light? OK I'm leaving ------> [] *clac*

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$a^2+b^2=0 \pmod{p} \Rightarrow a^2=(-1)b^2 \pmod{p}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $c\equiv ab^{-1}$, we have $c^2\equiv a^2b^{-2}$.  Also:

$$a^2+b^2=p \implies a^2 + b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

Now multiply by $b^{-2}$ to get:

$$a^2b^{-2} + 1 \equiv 0\pmod p\implies c\equiv -1\pmod p$$

Comment: Why is $c^2=a^2b^{-2}$? Is z mod mz abelian?

Comment: @gs2431 of course it is, and so is the unit group, since integer addition/multiplication are commutative.